# prove that an integral is between 2 values

Tags: integration, inequality

i am trying to prove that:

$$\frac{e}{2}\le \int _{\frac{1}{2}}^2\:\frac{e^x}{3x}dx\:\le \frac{e^2}{4}$$

I tried building the integral beginning both from $$1/2 < x < 2$$ as well as using the max and min values of 3x function and thus $$3/2<3x<6$$ but I couldn't make it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It suffices to show
$$\frac{e}{3} \le \frac{e^x}{3x} \le \frac{e^2}{6}$$
for all $x \in [1/2, 2]$, since the interval has length $3/2$.

You can do this by showing that $e^x/(3x)$ has a local minimum at $x=1$, and increases as you move away from $x=1$ in either direction. The maximum is achieved at $x=2$.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply to this

Comment: @angryavian is this because the integrals will preserve the monotonicity? Also can we sort of see that the maximum reached is at the max input value as $e$ is a strictly increasing function ? i.e., $x_1<x_2$ implies $e^{x_1}<e^{x_1}$ since we are in the positive reals.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame The function is not strictly increasing because of the $1/x$ term.

Comment: @angryavian aha good catch thanks!!

Comment: @GiannhsMeh After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).